How to get the http status code after call avformat_seek_file of ffmpeg?
How to get the http status code after call avformat_seek_file of ffmpeg to get a http url video?
I have a video source which is provided as a http url link, I want to get a snapshot of it , so I call avformat_seek_file to find a frame, but I find that it returns value is not < 0, even if the http call not return 200 or 206, so I want to know how to get the response of http calling in avformat_seek_file.
